# How to pass variable from browser to Protractor

Tags: angularjs, http, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm testing a single page application which makes a GET request to a given api endpoint, expecting some result.

Now, I've mocked the API using the $httpbackend object and I need to assert that the correct URL is passed to it (when performing the GET requet).

My URL contains a number of extra information the API needs to know (startTime, endTime and more). I just want to test that the right stuff is passed in.

This is my current end to end test:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiPromise = require("chai-as-promised");
var HttpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy');
var utils = require('../utils.js');
var expect = chai.expect;
var dateTimeSupport = require('../dateTimeFillSupport.js');
var support = require('../uhhSupport.js');
chai.use(chaiPromise);


var steps = function(){
    var proxy = null;
    var urlFound = "";

    this.Before(function(event, callback){
        proxy = new HttpBackend(browser);
        callback();
    }); 

    this.After(function(event, callback){
        proxy.onLoad.reset();
        callback();
    });



    this.Given(/^my given$/, function(){
        // Set up the context for the proxy - to be able to pass stuff back and forth
        var simpleChartData = require('data.json');
        proxy.context = {
            chartData   : simpleChartData,
            foundUrl    : urlFound
        };

        // Allow components and directived to pass through
        proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/\.\/components\/.+/).passThrough();
        proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/directives\/.+/).passThrough();           
        proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/.+\/api\/pvValues\/.+/).respond(function(method, url){
            $httpBackend.context.foundUrl = url;
            return [200, $httpBackend.context.chartData];
        });

            // perform action
        browser.get(utils.baseUrl);
        $('.dateLabel').click();

        return browser.controlFlow().execute(function(){});
    });

    this.When(/^a card is clicked$/, function(){        
        return dateTimeSupport.clickTheFirstCard().then(function(){
            $('.etChart').isDisplayed();
        });
    });

    this.Then(/^the correct URL is passed to the mocked API$/, function(){
    var expectedUrl = "myexpectedurl";
// here I want to check expectedUrl against $httpBackend.context.foundUrl
            return browser.controlFlow().execute(function(){});
        });
    }

    module.exports = steps;
```

So the question is, how can I pass the `$httpBackend.context.foundUrl` variable to my `then` function? (in order to see if ti matches the expected URL?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a global variable to the browser window in the `respond` function inside the `Given`:

```
proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/.+\/api\/pvValues\/.+/).respond(function(method, url){
        window.foundUrl = url;
        return [200, $httpBackend.context.chartData];
    });
```

In the `Then`, you get the browser to execute a script to return the global to protractor:

```
    this.Then(/^the correct URL is passed to the mocked API$/, function(){
        var expectedUrl = "myexpectedurl";
        // here I want to check expectedUrl against $httpBackend.context.foundUrl
        return browser.executeScript('return window.foundUrl').then(function(theUrl){
            expect(theUrl === expectedUrl).to.be.true;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you David! Your name sounds familiar! ;-)

Comment: @slimerdude please have a look here :-)